# testing auto 4L60E transmission while not in vehicle

Tags: automatic-transmission, testing, gm, 4l60e

is it possible to test while not installed in vehicle my auto 4L60E transmission

Comment: Provide it with power, cooling and control systems ie a test-bed, should test fine...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It depends on what state of assembly/disassembly your transmission is in, but you can do air checks on the transmission, which is a common way to go about it. I don't have time to research right now, [but these videos might help](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=4l60e+air+check).